# What counts as verification in Firebase Phone Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase charges about $0.06 per *verification*. Does that mean they only charge AFTER the user successfully verifies his phone? Or do they charge everytime a user requests a code?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the question mark, "*?*", in the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) it says

> Prices are per successful verification.
>
> On the Blaze plan, Phone Authentication provides a perpetual free
>   tier. The first 10K verifications are provided for free each month.
>   You are only charged on usage past this free allotment.
>
> All other Firebase Auth features are free to use on all plans.

Comment: The google provided explanation is not clear to me... if I have 1000 users who each login 4 times a month am I billed 1000 or 4000 authentications?

Comment: Please disregard prior comment...makes sense after viewing https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: @Matt - this still doesn't seem clear after having a look, would you be billed 1000 or 4000 times as per your comment above?

Comment: Hi @bigmadwolf did you figure out if it's 1000 or 4000?

Comment: @RushwinJamdas I believe it to be 4000.

Comment: it is still not clear to me